# Does this code have a name?

Tags: coding-theory, sphere-packing

Hamming-distance-4 binary codes have a very direct relationship to sphere packings. That's because we can identify the codewords with the cosets of $\mathbb{Z}^n/(2\mathbb{Z})^n$, and Hamming-distance-4 translates to Euclidean-distance-2 (between coset elements). The corresponding sphere packings are periodic, but in general non-lattice. A famous example is Best's packing in ten dimensions, which has 40 cosets.

What would be the next such family of packings? Instead of specifying the periodicity by $(2\mathbb{Z})^n$, let's try the doubled checkerboard lattice, $2D_n$ (all even coordinates, coordinate sum divisible by 4). Codes would be the maximum-cardinality distance-2 subsets of the cosets of $\mathbb{Z}^n/(2D_n)$. Do these codes have a name?

By finding maximum independent sets of the distance-2 adjacency graphs I determined the center densities of the corresponding packings up to $n=8$. Perhaps not surprisingly, these exactly match the center densities you get with $\mathbb{Z}^n/(2\mathbb{Z})^n$. But surely this cannot continue, because $\mathbb{Z}^n/(2D_n)$ has twice as many cosets with which to build a packing.